# Adding radio buttons with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying use JQquery to add custom radio buttons to a parent element:

```
function createRadio(name, parentID, values) {
  var parent = $('#' + parentId);
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      $('<input />', {
        type: 'radio',
        name: name,
        value: values[i]
    }).appendTo(parent);
    $('<label />', {
        'for': 'cb',
        text: values[i]
    }).appendTo(parent);
  }
}
```

However, this code works:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('<input type="radio" name="rad" value="a">').appendTo('#radios');
        $('<input type="radio" name="rad" value="b">').appendTo('#radios');
        $('<input type="radio" name="rad" value="b">').appendTo('#radios');
    });
```

But this doesn't:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        createRadio('rad', 'radios', ['a', 'b', 'c']);
    });
```

The HTML has a div who id is `radios`:

```
 <div id="radios">Radios</div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please provide the definition to the `parent` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct but you've mistaken in spellings `parentID` and `parentId`.

Check spelling of **`parentID`** in both function declaration (`function createRadio(name, parentID, values)`) parameters and `var parent = $('#' + parentId);`

It should be,

```
function createRadio(name, parentID, values) {
var parent = $('#' + parentID);
.....
.....
.....
```